# [F#]; [Compilation error]; Cannot compile any F# program

Tags: .net, f#, visual-studio-2017

### I just started programming in F# (using Visual Studio 2017 on windows 10) and I can't compile any F# program I try to write.

I created a console application and wrote some code but got stuck immediately as the compilation failed:

```
open System
printf "hello world"
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

And here's what i got:

> Error    FS0193  The module/namespace 'System.Collections.Generic' from
>   compilation unit 'mscorlib' did not contain the namespace, module or
>   type 'IReadOnlyCollection`1'

---

I also tried a simpler version:

```
printf "Hey"
```

And got that:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

---

I tried to repair Visual Studio through the Visual Studio Installer but it did not help.

Comment: You were referencing different versions of FSharp.Core or maybe missing the reference to it. You should probably `nuget` FSharp.Core to make sure you have the latest versions, and also have binding redirects (although in this simple case it shouldn't matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a brand new solution and it worked perfectly fine... I still don't know what the problem was though...

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by deleting references to `mscorlib` and rebuilding (VS2017)